# After 1 year, I cannot create a new chat room even though my ban was supposed to be over

Tags: discussion, chat, banning, account-suspension

When I joined Stack Overflow (I was a new user), I got banned for one month, with a ban end date of *11 Sept 2016 at 23:41* as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Now, it is *30 Sept 2017*, but I am still banned from creating a new chat room. I have not been banned for so long, and I'm always get this message when I access [this URL](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new):

> You are currently banned from creating new rooms.

My question is:

- Why am I still banned (I have not been banned or kicked for so long)?
- What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The chat system prevents you from creating rooms when you've been kicked in chat enough to trigger a certain threshold. This isn't a timed restriction though and has to be manually removed by a moderator.

We discussed this closer to the time (more than once I believe) and I didn't believe there was reason to remove that restriction then. However, time moves on and people change and all that...

The restriction is lifted now. Remember though - be nice and be responsible.